# change sysmbol or icon when menu toggles

Tags: menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle

I am trying to figure out how to get a menu-icon button to change when a toggle occurs...same concept as when a menu icon changes from the hamburger bun icon to a X between toggles. I am using the bootstrap 3 framework and for some reason am having trouble getting the icon to alternate between opening and closing the side-bar menu (the toggle works fine just can't get the icon to change when toggle occurs). I am assuming this is a universally achieved with the bootstraps CSS and JS frameworks...any and all help is greatly appreciated!

```
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS - Uses Bootswatch Flatly Theme: http://bootswatch.com/flatly/ -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/jquery-mobile.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Timeline CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body id="page-top" class="index">
 <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav"><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <h3>
                       DDI Work
                    </h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Landscapes</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Pavements</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Pools & Spas</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Walls</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Outdor Features</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Gardens</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <br><br><br><a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default"  id="menu-toggle"><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>         
            <span class="fa arrow">::before</span>          
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>

<!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="js/freelancer.js"></script>

<!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
<script>
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example with Glyphicon, but you can do it with any font. Instead of span:before you can use fa:before since you're using font awesome.

http://jsbin.com/betibo/1/edit

CSS:

```
#wrapper.toggled #menu-toggle span:before {content:'\2212'}
```

Change the content here to the unicode of the toggled class

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-primary"  id="menu-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a> 
  </div>
```

jQuery -- same as you had

Comment: Ok, got everything to work with the Glyphicon, so thanks again... but I just have another question on how to reverse the order of the side-bar menu-toggle...both the icons that appear when toggled and when the homepage is loaded (have the side-bar be closed when the page is loaded instead of starting open)...thanks again

Comment: Can't really understand this fully without a Bin or Bootply. But if I intuit it, it's the reverse, stick the closed icon in your html and then change the unicode in your css to be the one that shows when open.

Comment: ok, I apologize for any confusion...got the icon switch working.